# How to copy data afrer "cards"/"datalines" in SAS

Tags: sas

I have to perform statistical analysis on a file with hundreds of observations and 7 variables(columns)on SAS. I know that it is necessary to insert all the observations after "cards" or "datalines". But I can't write them all obviously. How can I do? Moreover, the given data file already is .sas7bdat.
Then, since (in my case) the multiple correspondence analysis requires only six of the seven variables, does this affect what I have to write in INPUT or/and in CARDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use CARDS when you're trying to manually write a data set. If you already have a SAS data set (sas7bdat) you can usually use that directly (there are some exceptions but likely don't apply here).

First create a libname to the folder where the file is:

```
libname myFiles 'path to fodler with sas file';
```

Then load it into your work library - this is a temporary space that is cleaned up when you're done so no files here are saved permanently.
This copies it over to that library - which is often faster.

```
data myFileName;
  set myFiles.myFileName;
run;
```

You can just work with the file from that library by referencing it as `myFiles.myFileName` in your code.

```
 proc means data=myFiles.myFileName;
 run;
```

This should get you started, but you should take the SAS free e-course to understand the basics, it will save you time overall.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell SAS to use the dataset.  INPUT statement (and CARDS/DATALINES or INFILE statement) are for reading from text files.

```
proc corresp data='/my directory/mydataset.sas7bdat' .... ;
  ...
run;
```

You could also make a libref that points to the directory and use two level name to reference the dataset.

```
libname myfiles '/my directory/';
proc corresp data=myfiles.mydataset .... ;
  ...
run;
```